# multiple image upload does'nt work with carrier wave in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, nested-attributes, cloudinary

I tried to uplaod multiple image in active_admin using carrierwave. so take a array field as per carrierwave documentation , and permit nested field , but after uploading multiple image i  got an error.

```
    error:
     AdminUser Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
       (0.3ms)  BEGIN
      SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "albums" ("title", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "dvdfbfdbfdb"], ["created_at", 2016-08-10 18:36:56 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-08-10 18:36:56 UTC]]
      SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "images" ("created_at", "updated_at", "avatars", "avatarable_id", "avatarable_type") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", 2016-08-10 18:36:56 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-08-10 18:36:56 UTC], ["avatars", "{kfos6fofbk1pbhrw2a5x.png,meaxlow3fgehcoepklm7.jpg}"], ["avatarable_id", 22], ["avatarable_type", "Album"]]
      SQL (1.8ms)  UPDATE "images" SET "avatars" = 'image/upload/v1470854220/kfos6fofbk1pbhrw2a5x.png' WHERE "images"."id" = $1  [["id", 23]]
       (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4632ms (ActiveRecord: 4.7ms)



    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  malformed array literal: "image/upload/v1470854220/kfos6fofbk1pbhrw2a5x.png"
    LINE 1: UPDATE "images" SET "avatars" = 'image/upload/v1470854220/kf...
                                            ^
    DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
    : UPDATE "images" SET "avatars" = 'image/upload/v1470854220/kfos6fofbk1pbhrw2a5x.png' WHERE "images"."id" = $1):

    activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `async_exec'
    activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `block in exec_no_cache'
    activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:566:in `block in log'
    activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
    activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:560:in `log'
    activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `exec_no_cache'
    activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:587:in `execute_and_clear'
    activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:116:in `exec_delete'
    activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:133:in `update'
    activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `update'



ActiveAdmin.register Album do

 permit_params :title,images_attributes: [:id,:_destroy,:avatars=>[]]

 form html: { multipart: true } do |f|

      f.inputs  do
        f.input :title
         f.has_many :images, allow_destroy: true do |a|
           a.input :avatars, :as => :file ,input_html:{multiple: true}
         end
      end
       f.actions
   end
end



class Album < ApplicationRecord


        has_many :images, as: :avatarable, dependent: :destroy
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
        end

    class Image < ApplicationRecord
          belongs_to :avatarable, polymorphic: true
          mount_uploaders :avatars, AvatarUploader
    end




    # encoding: utf-8

    class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
       include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
       def extension_white_list
           %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
       end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different approach to accomplish multiple uploads.
Try to see this sample project for example:
https://github.com/taragano/Cloudinary_multiple_uploads

Comment: Thanks @Taragano , but here i am trying to store multiple images in a array type field, this is not correct answer.

Comment: is you found solution ? @Itay Taragano